# strong deformation retract of $T=([0,1]\times\left\{0\right\})\cup(\cup_{\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}(\left\{q\right\}\times[0,q]))$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have the following problem: Let $\hat{T}$ be the set obtained by reflecting $T$ across the line $x=y$ and translating the result by $(0,-1)$. Now let $X_0=T\cup \hat{T}$ and for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, let $X_n$ be the set $X_0$ translated by $(n,n)$. Set $X:=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}X_n$.

For reference I include my definitions of (strong) deformation retracts here: A subspace $A\subseteq X$ is a deformation retract of $X$ if $\exists$ a homotopy $F:X\times[0,1]\to X$ s.t. \begin{equation*}
F(X,0)=X,  F(X,1)=A\text{  and  }F(a,1)=a\forall a\in A
\end{equation*}
whereas for a strong deformation retract, the last equation has to hold $\forall t\in [0,1]$.

a) Any point $x\in X$ is a deformation retract of $X$.

b) No point $x\in X$ is a strong deformation retract of $X$.

My ideas/attempts:

a)$X$ has no 'loops' and if one point is on one of the 'spikes' we get from drawing $X$, we can just 'slide it down' and are then on one of the translations of $[0,1]$ and conclude.

b) I want to show that $X$ is nowhere locally path-connected which would then tell me that no $x\in X$ can be a strong deformation retract of $X$. However, considering for example $(0,0)\in X$, I think I could find a locally path-connected neighborhood of it, so I think I am missing something here. Does anybody know how I could resolve my issue?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Should (b) have *strong* deformation retract? It would be helpful to include the definitions of strong deformation retract and deformation retract, or at least the difference between the two, since terminologies vary.

Comment: About your argument for (a), not every path connected space deformation retracts to a point.

Comment: @ronno You are right, I corrected my first attempt, I think this should work. With the added definition of strong deformation retract, do you have any idea how I would go about solving b)?

Answer (score 0):

For (a), you have to be a little careful because either you need to contract the "spikes" at different rates or also move the points on the long zigzag line along with them (but then this also needs to "drag along" the points on the spikes). But that's roughly the idea.

For (b), a reasonable intermediate lemma is that if any $X$ deformation retracts to $x \in X$ then $x$ has a basis of contractible neighborhoods in $X$. But the specific $X$ we are dealing with is not locally path connected at any point.